# Find the SQL Server error log on a Linux machine

Tags: sql-server

I have installed Mssql-Server on a Linux machine.
Can anyone help me to find the SQL Server error log?

Answer (score 8):

Go to the default location of SQL Server Error Log file on a Linux machine

Syntext :--

> cd /var/opt/mssql/log
>
> ls -lrt

Here you can find the errorlog file of SQL Server

-rw-rw---- 1 mssql mssql   15838 Dec 22 16:26 errorlog

To check the content of errorlog

> cat errorlog